Updating all pickers based on another pickers
I have a shiny app that is spread out on multiple based where the user needs to select a dataset and column. In one of the tabs I have a pickerInput with an actionButton that is suppose to update the dataset and column. It has a side-effect, when I run it, the dataset and column is updated but then the individual observeEvents and ran and the pickerInputs for the columns gets blank. How can I avoid this?
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Dataset1"),
  pickerInput("select_dataset1", "Dataset:", choices = c("iris", "mtcars", "ToothGrowth")),
  pickerInput("select_columns1",  "Columns:", c(), multiple = TRUE),
  tags$h1("Dataset2"),
  pickerInput("select_dataset2", "Dataset:", choices = c("iris", "mtcars", "ToothGrowth")),
  pickerInput("select_columns2",  "Columns:", c(), multiple = TRUE),
  tags$br(),
  tags$h1("Update All"),
  pickerInput("select_dataset3", "Dataset:", choices = c("iris", "mtcars", "ToothGrowth")),
  pickerInput("select_columns3",  "Columns:", c(), multiple = TRUE),
  actionButton("update_all", "Update All")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  observeEvent(input$select_dataset1, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, "select_columns1", choices = colnames(get(input$select_dataset1)))
    
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$select_dataset2, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, "select_columns2", choices = colnames(get(input$select_dataset2)))
    
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$select_dataset3, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, "select_columns3", choices = colnames(get(input$select_dataset3)))
    
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$update_all, {
    
   dataset <- input$select_dataset3
   columns <- input$select_columns3
   
   updatePickerInput(session, "select_dataset1", selected = dataset)
   updatePickerInput(session, "select_dataset2", selected = dataset)
   updatePickerInput(session, "select_columns1", selected = columns)
   updatePickerInput(session, "select_columns2", selected = columns)
    
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


One workaround I'm using is reactiveVal, but curious about other solutions.
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$h1("Dataset1"),
  pickerInput("select_dataset1", "Dataset:", choices = c("iris", "mtcars", "ToothGrowth")),
  pickerInput("select_columns1",  "Columns:", c(), multiple = TRUE),
  tags$h1("Dataset2"),
  pickerInput("select_dataset2", "Dataset:", choices = c("iris", "mtcars", "ToothGrowth")),
  pickerInput("select_columns2",  "Columns:", c(), multiple = TRUE),
  tags$br(),
  tags$h1("Update All"),
  pickerInput("select_dataset3", "Dataset:", choices = c("iris", "mtcars", "ToothGrowth")),
  pickerInput("select_columns3",  "Columns:", c(), multiple = TRUE),
  actionButton("update_all", "Update All")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  picker1 <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  picker2 <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$select_dataset1, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, "select_columns1", choices = colnames(get(input$select_dataset1)), selected = picker1())
    picker1(NULL)
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$select_dataset2, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, "select_columns2", choices = colnames(get(input$select_dataset2)), selected = picker2())
    picker2(NULL)
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$select_dataset3, {
    
    updatePickerInput(session, "select_columns3", choices = colnames(get(input$select_dataset3)))
    
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$update_all, {
    
   dataset <- input$select_dataset3
   columns <- input$select_columns3
   
   updatePickerInput(session, "select_dataset1", selected = dataset)
   updatePickerInput(session, "select_dataset2", selected = dataset)
   updatePickerInput(session, "select_columns1", selected = columns)
   updatePickerInput(session, "select_columns2", selected = columns)
   
   picker1(columns)
   picker2(columns)
    
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

